# Which one layer fits best for Java DTO's mappers, Service layer or Controller layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, dto

Recently I started thinking about @Transactional and how it works and the performance and I have a project where I use spring transactions, so I have such code:

```
@Transactional
public PageableProductsDTO getUsersProducts(String userName, Pageable page) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize(), Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt");
    Page<Product> pagebelProductsByUser = productRepository.findProductsByUser(userService.getUser(userName), pageRequest);
    Page<ProductDetailsDto> productDtos = pagebelProductsByUser.map(source -> {
        ProductDetails productDetails = source.getProductDetails();
        return new ProductDetailsDto(productDetails.getBarcode(), productDetails.getName(), productDetails.getPrice());
    });
    return new PageableProductsDTO(productDtos);
}
```

As you can see, in the above method I fetch products from db, and then map the products to the **PageableProductsDTO**, I have doubts whether I do it right, because maybe the dto mapping should be done in controller layer? And also it seems that doing such mapping in the service layer will prolong time spent for transaction itself, I mean maybe it's not good in perspective of performance?

Answer (score 1):

*There’s no universal solution, only the one that suits you best. It’s not about DTOs being pattern or anti-pattern, it’s about do you need them or not.... and why*

One part of the question is if you should re-pack data in *controller* or *service* layer. That depends fully on if you introduced DTOs to separate data and business logic of your application layers **OR** you introduced DTOs to re-pack data (maybe remove some private properties) that will be returned to the client *(if latter is the case, controller should do the business).*

Although performance impact looks negligible in this case, you should<sup>1</sup> move logic of loading data from DB in separate method and mark that one<sup>2</sup> as Transactional.

<sup>1</sup> Separation of methods will allow you to re-use code that loads data from DB inside service layer, without need to re-pack data back to entities.

<sup>2</sup>*This will be good pattern as long as you want to commit a transaction after executing db load. If you want to re-use method for loading data from DB please consider other use-cases and if you want to prolong committing.*